# Accessing Memory which does not exist ??( K&R exercise )

Tags: c

I am pretty new to using pointers and am using K&R as referrence , I was trying to create a pointer to pointer to store the base addresses of all line strings and then using quicksorting to sort the lines( Its an exercise in K&R ) . On doing that i stumbled upon the dreaded Segmentation Fault . Following is the code used :-( On debugging the point at which segmentation fault occurs is also pointed in the code below which shows up in Partition Function )

```
int main( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
    char *Lines[MAXLINES] ;
    Lines[0] = "Premier League is the best .\n" ;
    Lines[1] = "Manchester United \n" ;
    Lines[2] = "KOlkata \n" ;

    Quicksort( Lines , 0 , 2 ) ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <3 ; i++ ) 
        printf("%s" , *(Lines + i) ) ;
    return 0 ;
}

void Quicksort( char *line[MAXLINES] , int start , int end )
{
    if( start >= end )
        return ;
    else {
        int Pindex = Partition( line , start , end ) ;
        Quicksort( line , start , Pindex - 1 ) ;
        Quicksort( line , Pindex + 1 , end ) ;
    }
}

int Partition( char *line[MAXLINES] , int start , int end )
{
    char *pivot ;
    pivot = *( line + end ) ; // Segmentation Fault shows up here 
    int Pindex = start ;
    for( int i = start ; i <= end ; i++ ) {
        if( strcmp( *(line + i) , pivot ) < 0 ) {
            Swap( line , i , Pindex ) ;
            Pindex++ ;
        }
    } 
    return --Pindex ;
}

void Swap( char *line[] , int index1 , int index2 )
{
    char *temp ;
    temp = *(line + index1) ;
    *(line + index1 ) = *( line + index2 ) ;
    *( line + index2 ) = temp ;
}
```

Thanks For Helping Out !!!

Comment: Do you have library header files included? Do you have function declarations (prototypes)?

Comment: The recursion runs out of control with `Quicksort` called with `start = 0` and `end = 2` or `end = -2` until the stack breaks. I suggest you deploy a debugger to find the fault. A transcription error?

Comment: On using a debugger location of segmentation fault shows up and its location is shown in the code above. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: As the code manages to pass `end = -2` that will very likely result in indexing `char *Lines[]` out of range, resulting in your case with a segmentation fault, in my case with a stack overflow, but that's the nature of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it . The problem was i did not allocate memory to the strings which I pointed the memory address of therefore the segmentation fault . Thanks everyone who took their time and responded to my query to help me out . Thanks for your help !!!